# Как включить картинки в war-архив?

Tags: java, развертывание, wildfly

На локальном инстансе у меня прописаны относительные пути до папки с картинками, но я заметил, что в war эта папка не входит, соответственно, в приложении запущенном на сервере картинки не отображаются. Как включить картинки, добавить папку с картинками в war (каким образом?) или прописать абсалютные пути и хранить картинки где-нибудь в другом месте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы не используете фронтенд в виде *apache / nginx* для предоставления доступа к статическим ресурсам, то они должны находиться в WAR файле. При этом ссылки на статические ресурсы должны быть прописаны с учетом `ContextPath`.

Любая система сборки, как то [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) или [Gradle](http://gradle.org/), может поместить файлы из внешнего каталога в WAR на этапе сборки приложения, но было бы гораздо логичнее, если бы они туда помещались автоматически.

Например, в Maven для этого существует [стандартная структура каталогов](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) приложения. Если ваши изображения находятся в каталоге `src/main/webapp/static/images`, то после развертывания приложения они будут доступны по абсолютной `http(s)://<ipaddr:port>/${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/static/images` или относительной `/${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/static/images` ссылке

В этом примере `ContextPath` указан с использованием `JSTL`. В зависимости от используемого фреймворка и разметки, есть способы сделать это по другому.